# Stop PDF from Opening if Client has no Viewer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, firefox, pdf

I'm trying to open a PDF in a web browser, but when I do it downloads the PDF instead which I'm assuming it's because the user has no viewer (Firefox - Mac). My client also has Google Docs blocked from the server so embedding that is out of the option. We tried Scribd but that kept replacing some of our bullet images with funny characters.

So What I'm trying to do now is come up with some kind of conditional statement which would say that if the user does not have a reader or is trying to download/open PDF - show some text with a link to download a viewer. I'm assuming I would need PHP and Javascript but maybe not. Is this possible?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/PDFReader/

Comment: @Rocket you should make that an answer.

Comment: You could just put an interstitial page "Click here for the PDF. If you don't have a pdfreader, click here to get one" kind of thing.

Comment: You may be able to detect with javascript whether a pdf-reader-plugin is installed, but you will not be able to determine whether a viewer is installed if the viewer is a separate application.  Moreover, even if the viewer is installed, the users may disable opening the pdf in the plugin in browser preferences - in which case the "save as" dialog box will always pop up anyway.  Maybe you need to rethink the problem.

Comment: Most people dislike reading PDFs in the browser anyway. On all my sites, PDF files are served with `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Comment: What's so terrible about just having a generic comment that shows up for everyone? *This content requires PDF viewing software.* Probably not a solid solution if you have a million PDF links around the site, but it seems more appropriate than trying to hijack a session this way.

Answer (score 0):

This will be impossible. That is client information that the server can't access. You either let them download it or you create/use a custom embeder.

Answer (score 0):

I did I bit of Googling, and I found this: http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/PDFReader/

It looks promising, try it out.